# How to build links compatible with clean and "dirty" URLs?

Tags: 7, navigation, uri

I have a development site that doesn't support clean URLs, my production site does support them.
If I build a link in the body of a node like:

```
<a href="view-something/4,7">View something</a>
```

This shows ok on my production site but gives a 404 while in development site.
How do I build universally good URLs ?

Comment: do you want to give links to other nodes or some external urls

Comment: Just to other nodes, internal links, for example to a view, as in the given example.

Comment: You can try http://drupal.org/project/link_node module, but this works for node link only

Comment: So, there is no functionality in core for this kind of links ? I was expecting some kind of "use `[link]`" answer :)

Comment: I must be missing something, or are you just asking for [url()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/url/7)?

Comment: Have you tried with Menu token module http://drupal.org/project/menu_token

Comment: hey did you got any solution ?

Comment: @mohit_rocks no, not yet.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to define such Links with the menu_hook

http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7

Especially lookt at the Wildcard options i used them recently to define own urls